# PSN sharing games

Tags: ps3, psn

I buy & download a game from PSN on my user account on PS3 #1. Then I switch to PS3 #2 and login with the same PSN account. Can I download the same game without paying twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Just go to your download list and redownload it on your PS3 #2.

Since November 18th, PlayStation restrict [sharing](http://www.vg247.com/2011/11/04/sony-changes-psn-game-sharing-policy-for-ps3-and-psp/) from 5 devices down to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the maximum number of devices (PS3 or PSP) that can share the same PSN account is five.

Comment: Since November 18th, Sony changes PSN game sharing policy. See my post edit.